# How to stop timer in react native

Tags: react-native

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, TextInput, Button, Alert, Switch } from 'react-native';
import TimerMixin from 'react-timer-mixin';

export default class home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { switchstate: false, timer: null };
    var timer = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
    this.setState({ timer });
  }
  tick = async () => {
    return await console.log('asdas', 'iam printing')
  }

  toogleswitchstate = () => {
    if (this.state.switchstate == false) {
      this.setState({ switchstate: true })
    } else if (this.state.switchstate == true) {
      this.setState({ switchstate: false })
      clearInterval(this.timer);
      //geolocation.stopObserving();
    }
    console.log(this.state.switchstate)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-evenly', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: datum.secondaryColor }}>
        <Button
          title={String(this.state.switchstate)}
          onPress={() => this.toogleswitchstate()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I designed this code to trigger the timer when this component is executed, but I don't know  how to stop the timer, i have cropped the code for stack overflow restriction

**Expected behaviour:**
the toogleswitchstate function will stop the timer

**What actually happened:**
Throws me a weird error

Comment: I think you also have to change state after clear interval, this.setState({timer:null})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working code

Correction in code:-

1) setInterval is side effect, so should be in componentDidMount.

2) No need to fill timer in state as it is an instance variable.

3) Variables name should be camel cased like switchState instead of switchstate.

4) Remove timer in componentWillUnmount if not already removed.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, TextInput, Button, Alert, Switch } from 'react-native';
import TimerMixin from 'react-timer-mixin';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { switchState: false };
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.timer = setInterval(this.tick, 5000);
  }
  tick = async () => {
   await console.log('asdas', 'iam printing');
  }
  toogleSwitchState = () => {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
    if (this.state.switchState == false) {
      this.setState({ switchState: true })
    } else {
      this.setState({ switchState: false })
      //geolocation.stopObserving();
    }
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.timer) clearInterval(this.timer)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'space-evenly', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: datum.secondaryColor }}>
        <Button
          title={String(this.state.switchState)}
          onPress={() => this.toogleSwitchState()}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Note sure why you want to clear timer when switch state is true. If that's not the intention you could simply write

```
this.setState({
    switchState: !this.state.switchState
})
```

to toggle switchState.

Hope that helps!!!